# Problemas para instalar gema sqlite en Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Si intento hacer un nuevo proyecto con `rails new myApp`

Obtengo siempre el mismo error, tanto si uso esta forma de instalación, como si instalo cada pieza por separado...

> Gem files will remain installed in
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out
>
> An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' succeeds
>   before bundling.

Asi que lo siguiente que hago es instalar sqlite 3 con...

```
gem install sqlite3 -v 1.4.0
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error...

> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe -r
>   ./siteconf20190325-12592-s7pzr4.rb extconf.rb checking for
>   sqlite3.h... no sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from
>   http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

He leido y leido para solucionar este error y aqui lo explica exactamente

http://rubyonwindowsguides.github.io/book/ch02-05.html

Pero cuando descargo sqlite spapshoot manualmente en el paso en el que debo hacer la configuracion con el siguiente comando...

```
ruby setup.rb config -- --with-sqlite3-include=c:\projects\sqlite-autoconf-3080600
```

Sigo obteniendo errores con flopen...

Comment: ¿a que te refieres con flopen? ¿verificaste que efectivamente existe el archivo `sqlite3.h` en la carpeta `c:\projects\sqlite-autoconf-3080600`? ¿te arrojó algún error al compilar? Quizás podrías probar a seguir [estos pasos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16023062/895789) y cuentas si te resultó o no.

Comment: Nada, al final instale ubuntu en una partición de mi disco duro y pude instalar ruby on rails sin problema. Es un dolor de cabeza instalarlo en Windows la verdad.

Comment: Si, en general es lo mejor correrlo en un S.O. Unix-like. A la larga te ahorrarás muchos dolores de cabeza

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente descargas 2 archivos de esta pagina https://sqlite.org/download.html
De la sección precompiled binaries for windows y sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3280000.zip
y el sqlite-dll 32 o 64 dependiendo de tu sistema.

Luego creas una carpeta sqlite en tu disco duro, y extraes todos los archivos necesarios de ambos archivos.

Al extraer todo lo necesario, agrega los bin al path de windows "Enviroment variables" y agregas Sqlite/bin.

Pruebas que funcione escribinedo sqlite3 en la consola, y te devolverá la version.

Deberias hacer el gem install de sqlite y si no funciona entonces no se más nada.